# printf gives WARNING only

Tags: c, warnings, printf, stdio

Can anyone tell me why *not* including `stdio.h` and still using the `printf` function only gives a warning on gcc?

> warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

Rather this should be a compile error, as we are including a function that is not declared.

Does this have something to do with the linking procedure? Please elaborate.

Comment: Keywords: *implicit declaration*

Comment: @chris are there any more such keywords? and how the compiler links to this declaration?

Comment: Ok, sorry, the "please elaborate" part just reminded me of the way assignments are frequently phrased.

Comment: @akash, You haven't given it a signature, so it guesses for you. If that guess is wrong (which it usually is), the linker complains because now it can't match it up. It's just warning you that it had to guess.

Comment: @chris does that means the compiler makes a right guess for the printf  so it gives a warning only and links it to the declaration provided?

Comment: @akash, The keyword there is *incompatible*. I should've said it's warning you that it makes a wrong guess. It has to guess the same signature for every function so the chance of it being right is slim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you don't supply signatures for functions that you use in your code, the compiler will (implicitly) make some assumptions about what the unknown function accepts as an argument list, and returns as result.

These assumptions are based on your usage of the function, so e.g. given `printf("%s", (char *) string)`, the compiler will decide that `printf` is a function that takes exactly 2 `char *` - **not** a variable argument list - and returns an `int`.

Problems can then occur during *linking*, when these assumptions turn out to be incompatible with the actual function.

Answer (score 6):

pb2q's answer is correct. This answer provides some additional explanation about the particular warning message you brought up.

GCC defines a built-in function for `printf`. The built-in function has the proper prototype:

```
int printf(const char *, ...);
```

However, an implicit declaration assumes a fixed number arguments. So, assume your program looked like:

```
int main () {
    printf("%s\n", "Hello, World!");
    return 0; // not required in C 2011
}
```

Then the implicit declaration for `printf` would be:

```
int printf(char *, char *);
```

Which doesn't match the type of the built-in function, hence the wording of the warning. It is likely you got a warning message just before that message that complains about the lack of prototype to begin with.

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf'
```

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with your compiler and default libraries.  If you are linking against a standard library where printf is already used (a debug version perhaps), then printf will be in the global namespace and be linked.  The compiler is warning you that you haven't explicitly declared printf.  You can turn on -Werror to make all warnings errors, then the compiler won't let it get to the linker stage.